# Linux terminal script to create boilerplate files in current working directory with one varying word?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, code-generation, boilerplate

I have to create two boilerplate files, both of which always have the same content, with the EXCEPTION of a single word. I'm thinking of creating a command or something that I can run in the Linux terminal (Ubuntu), along with an argument that represents the one word which can vary in the files created. Perhaps a batch file will accomplish this, but I don't know what it will look like.

I will be able to run this command every time I create these boilerplate files, instead of pasting the boilerplate and changing the one word in the file that has to be changed.

These file paths relative to my current working directory are:

registration.php

etc/module.xml

Comment: Just learn to use `cp` and `sed` (or `awk` or a `perl` one-liner) and combine them in a script. Done.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python script that reads in the file as string and replaces the occurrence would probably be the quickest. Something like:

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r+') as inputFile:
    txt=inputFile.read().replace('someword', 'replacementword')
    inputFile.seek(0)
    inputFile.write(txt)
    inputfile.close()
```